# MySQL replication not working when running a query from a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, replication

I have 2 servers with MySQL master-master replication set.
When I run an INSERT/UPDATE query from a PHP script on any of the servers it is replicated just fine on the other server.

Anyway, this won't happen when I run an UPDATE from a bash script: the value of a field will be updated only on the server where I run the bash script and won't be replicated on the other one.

Any ideas on why the replication won't work from a BASH script?

This is how a mysql update that only updates the local records looks like:
`mysql -B -N -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -h $HOST -e "UPDATE $DATABASE.$TABLE SET Status='-1' WHERE Id=$ID"`

Comment: the main purpose of replication is to set master as read/write and slave as read. If you do update on slave then its wrong.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty sorry, I meant master-master replication.

Comment: Are you using the same mysql user from the same host when you UPDATE/INSERT from the bash script. And also have you ever try to execute the .php script over the shell console instead from the browser.

Comment: @kpopovbg Yes, they use the same user and I am connecting to localhost on both servers. When I execute the PHP from command line the replication works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have `REPLICATE_DO_DB` set. Check it with `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`. It's a bit tricky: if you have it to replicate only `foo` database and you do something like this:

```
use bar; -- or even without it
UPDATE foo.table SET Status='-1' WHERE Id=69;
```

than it'll **NOT** be replicated. Make sure you `use` the database that you want to replicate.

Comment: This solved the issue, I just added `USE $DATABASE` before `UPDATE` and it worked as intended. Thank you!